How to set a session variable for a PDO object with DenodoODBC?
I’m working with large queries and long fields created using the GROUP_CONCAT function. The results of my queries appear to be truncated. After some research, I found that the group_concat_max_len parameter might be the issue.
However, I can’t figure out how to set it properly for my session.
Here is a minimal example of my problem:
<?php

$db = new PDO('odbc:DenodoODBC');

$db -> exec("SET SESSION group_concat_max_len=4096");

and the result :

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 7 ERROR: Syntax error: Exception parsing query near 'SESSION' java.sql.SQLException: Syntax error: Exception parsing query near 'SESSION'; Error while executing the query (SQLExecDirect[7] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_driver.c:241) in *.php:7 Stack trace: #0 *.php(7): PDO->exec('SET SESSION gro...') #1 {main} thrown in *.php on line 7


Are you actually accessing a MySQL database through your DenodoODBC connector?

Yes, other queries work perfectly fine. I can't show result for data protection purpose

This syntax error message does not come from mysql. Denodo is a data virtualisation platform if I'm not mistaken. It probably has its own flavour of sql that it can translate to whatever underlying database you have.

And also, it seems Dendoo doesn't support SET SESSION as well.

In your place, instead of asking about an XY problem, I would ask about exact problem you are having at hand, that is, seemingly truncated GROUP_CONCAT results.

Do you configure the JDBC URL somewhere? If you do, a solution is here.
